# What's the XmlnsDefinitionAttribute and XmlnsPrefix analog in Windows 8?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I can find a reference to a structure named XmlnsDefinitionAttribute, but cannot figure out how to set it on an assembly...

(What I want to achieve is the ability to give default xmlns prefix names for my various libraries)

Comment: "give default xmlns prefix names for my various libraries" me too ! A massive holdup to fluid RAD win win 8.1 store apps in XAML. Pain to refactor anything as have to update all my xmlns:blah="using statements in all xaml !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly I don't believe these attributes exist in the Windows 8 xaml stack. I'd be love to corrected on this one though.

Comment: (Leaving unanswered for a bit as you seem unsure. Will mark as answered if nobody comes up with a positive reply)

Comment: There is not `XmlnsDefinition`/`XmlnsPrefix` replacement in Windows Store apps, I'm looking for it a lot while building WinRT support in ReSharper 7. This is very confusing.